# Acumatica CustomizationPlugin in code file vs. dll

Tags: acumatica

When I create a CustomizationPlugin class in the online Acumatica code editor vs. within an extension library, my OnPublished event gets fired for the former, but not the latter, even though the code is the same. Do CustomizationPlugins work from an extension library? It happens regardless of the contents of the class, but I'll post some example source...

```
//Customization plugin is used to execute custom actions after customization project was published  
public class WebConfigurator : CustomizationPlugin
{
    private Configuration _WebConfig;

    private Configuration WebConfig
    {
        get
        {
            if (_WebConfig == null)
            {
                _WebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            }

            return _WebConfig;
        }
    }

    //This method executed right after website files were updated, but before website was restarted
    //Method invoked on each cluster node in cluster environment
    //Method invoked only if runtimecompilation is enabled
    //Do not access custom code published to bin folder, it may not be loaded yet
    public override void OnPublished()
    {
        this.WriteLog("OnPublished Event");

        SetAppSetting("DataPublisher:LoginPath", "auth/login");
        WebConfig.Save();
    }

    protected void SetAppSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)WebConfig.GetSection("appSettings");

        if (appSettingSection.Settings.AllKeys.Contains(key))
        {
            appSettingSection.Settings[key].Value = value;
        }
        else
        {
            appSettingSection.Settings.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    //This method executed after customization was published and website was restarted.  
    public override void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        this.WriteLog("UpdateDatabase Event");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add both sources of the classes

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "both" sources since it's the same code, but I just posted example source above.

Answer (score 1):

CustomizationPlugin inheritors will be executed only if they will go to App_RuntimeCode folder. If you create .dll file, it will not be executed. Everything related to CustomizationPlugin inheritors wil be executed only once. Another detail to keep in mind is that if you set UseRuntimeCompilation key in  section of the web.config file  to  False,  the  platform  uses  the  App_Code/Caches  folder instead the App_RuntimeCode and your inheritor will not be executed as well. By default UseRuntimeCompilation is set to true.

Comment: Good catch, the explanation is right there in the comments generated in the CustomizationPlugin stub and I missed it XD

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're not using UpdateDatabase() method as the entry point of the plugin instead?

I have a feeling this might be because you're modifying the web.config file. I would advise avoiding this if possible. Modifying web.config triggers a long chain of events and recompilation on IIS side and since we're already in the context of publishing and recompiling IIS file this might result in undefined behavior and hang of IIS server due to sporadic lock file conflicts.

I can't tell for `OnPublished` method as I haven't tested it but I'm not aware of any limitations with `UpdateDatabase` so I did a simple test by creating a new library from within the customization project editor:

[image]

I then added `PX.Web.Customization.dll` assembly in the library project because it's required to reference `Customization` type.
The project is as barebone as I could make it, it contains a single source code file named Test.cs:

```
using Customization;
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public class Test : CustomizationPlugin
    {
        public override void UpdateDatabase()
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

I then compiled the library (debug mode), pasted the compiled DLL files to the Bin folder of my Acumatica instance. I then created a new completely empty customization project. In Files section, with + button I added the 'Test.dll' library file, saved the project and then executed Publish With CleanUp.

Notice that the project contains no runtime code, only 1 library file. In the Publish console window I see that it executed the Test customization plugin and stopped because it did catch the exception I throw from within the plugin:
[image]